# Cant figure out the right Subquery(?) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a field in table1, holding IDs of table2, seperated by commas.

Now in a simple query I can easily get the IDs (e.g. '1,2,5,8,9'), but I want to see the associated values from table2. (e.g. 1=red,2=blue,5=yellow...)

I tried a query like this:

```
SELECT
  sp.id,
  (
      SELECT
          title
      FROM
          hopa_art_species_categories as ca1
      WHERE
          ca1.id IN (sp.categories)
  ) AS ca
FROM
  hopa_art_species as sp
```

but I only get the first value of 'title', not all of them.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

EDIT:

I'm sorry, I think it's not clear enough what I want. Here is an example:

table1 (people)

id name     haircolors

1. thomas   1,3
2. Anja     2
3. Fred     2,3,4
4. Sascha   1

table2 (colors)

1. red
2. blond
3. black
4. brown

SELECT haircolors FROM table1 wold give me just:

haircolors

1. 1,3
2. 2
3. 2,3
4. 1

But I want:

name   haircolors

1. Thomas red, black
2. Anja   blond
3. Fred   blond, black, brown
4. Sascha red

I hope this is a better eplaination ;)

Thanks

Comment: use simple inner join between both of tables and get the data

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM  hopa_art_species t1, hopa_art_species_categories t2
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( t2.id, t1.categories ) > 0
```

EDIT:

understood. Then, please try this.

```
SELECT t1.id, `name`, GROUP_CONCAT(color SEPARATOR ',') AS color_names
FROM  people t1, colors t2
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( t2.id, t1.haircolors ) > 0
GROUP BY t1.id, `name`
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's actually something else. I edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

```
SELECT sp.id, ( SELECT title FROM hopa_art_species_categories as ca1 WHERE ca1.id = sp.id ) AS ca 
FROM hopa_art_species as sp
```

You can do it as a JOIN too:

```
    SELECT sp.id, ho.title 
    FROM hopa_art_species as sp
    JOIN hopa_art_species_categories ho
    ON sp.id=ho.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but sadly it dowsnt work. The first example gives me only values when there is just one ID. When there are multiple values it just says [NULL], and the second example still gives me only the first IDs value.